# Python, pygame Couldn't open chic.jpg

Tags: python, pygame

I'm creating a small game with python. although that the program and the images are in the same folder, I don't see an image when I open the program. I have just black window, but I should see my pic. whats could be wrong?

And there is my code:

```
import os, sys
import pygame

class Game:
    def __init__(self, width=640, height=480):
        pygame.init()
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode([self.width, self.height])
    def MainLoop(self):
        self.ChickenLoad();

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                sys.exit()

        self.chicken_sprites.draw(self.screen)
        pygame.display.flip()

    def ChickenLoad(self):
        self.chicken = Chicken()
        self.chicken_sprites = pygame.sprite.Group(self.chicken)

class Chicken(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.image.load("duch.jpg")
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    MainWindow = Game()
    MainWindow.MainLoop()
```

Comment: your `Mainloop` is not a loop - there is no `while True`

Comment: I saw in previous question that you got error. Always add full error message to question.

Comment: maybe image is broken - try another file. And try another format - PNG.

Comment: I tried your code with my image and it works.

Comment: but now i don't get any error.. I've it already solved

Comment: I tried with another pics but it still does't work

Comment: I tried on Linux with .png image and it works. Maybe there is problem with file format or system. Can you see your file in any image viewer ?

Comment: yes I can. I have Python 3.5, maybe here is a problem?

Comment: you can try to generate image/surface `self.image = pygame.Surface( (50,50) )` and fill with red color `self.image.fill( (255,0,0) )` . And use it instead of file image.

Comment: I don't have Python 3.5 - I use 3.4 and 2.7 - so I can't check it. Do you use Linux/Windows/MacOS ?

Comment: maybe Google knows something about Python 3.5 and Pygame problem.

Comment: then maybe try Python 3.4 - and maybe try 32bit version.

Comment: doesn't worked... :/

Comment: btw: `kasia` and `duch` are Polish words - "Kate" and "ghost" - if you speek Polish there is [Polish Python Coders Group Forum](https://pl.python.org/forum/) and group on Facebook "[Python: pierwsze kroki](https://www.facebook.com/groups/pythonpierwszekroki/)"

Comment: there is "Anaconda" - Python with modules. Maybe they have better tested modules - https://www.continuum.io/downloads

Answer (score -1):

It is your trailing semi-colon that is preventing the photo to appear.

In my IDE, the semicolon is deemed unneeded, and it is right. After the removal of the semicolon, your program worked fine. So from this:

```
self.ChickenLoad();
```

to this:

```
self.ChickenLoad()
```

Comment: `;` has nothing to do with problem. You can use `;` in Python to put two command in one line. Code with `;` works for me on Linux.